# remote data update on iphone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, database, core-data

I created an iphone application that uses database. Here is the problem, this application should work offline. I am not going to use a remote database but i have to update these datas every 2 month. How can i update the datas that was already stored in application? What is the best way and keywords?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't the easiest to decipher..... but from what I gather...

If you don't have a web service to call (I guess this is what you mean by remote database??), then you're only option is to release an updated version of your app every 2 months with an updated database.

Comment: Although just chucking the latest complete set of data onto a server somewhere and fetching that would be the same thing as having a paramterless web service, I guess. So the author could do that — just refetch the file every two months.